# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest - missing data

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to read a text file using a synchronous request. It doesn't work but I get no errors or warnings either.

Can anyone enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong, please?

```
NSString *url = @"http://pappons.com/test.txt" ;

NSLog(@"getHTTPData: %@" , url ) ;
NSURLResponse* response = nil;

NSURLRequest* urlRequest =  [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil] ;

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog( @"data: %@" , myString ) ;
```

output:

```
2012-06-15 11:33:42.209 FrederikTest[1365:707] getHTTPData: http://pappons.com/test.txt 
2012-06-15 11:33:42.306 FrederikTest[1365:707] data:
```

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"Response:%d", ((HTTPResponse*) response).statusCode);` print?

Comment: in addition, making sync requests freeze the main thread..

Comment: ... if performed on the main thread.

Comment: @JamesWebster thanks I forgot to write it...It was implicit :)

Comment: code is good but perform on background process as it might freeze on main thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pass in `NSError` to check if error occurred

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! - Turns out that the phone's internet connection was disabled.